# Javascripts to remove text from HTML

Tags: javascript

I need a script to remove a line of text "Quantity in Stock:(Out of Stock)" from my product pages. The specific HTML code I'm trying to remove is:

```
<span class="PageText_L329n"><strong class="prod_qty_label">
      Quantity in Stock
    </strong></span>
      :
    <span style="color:#cc0000;"><span class="StockQuantity_OutOfStock"></span></span><br></br>
```

I only have limited knowledge of Javascript, and I know I need to start with something like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('', '');
```

But I'm struggling to make it work with having all the HTML markups in the javascript.

On my category pages (different page), I am trying to remove this text from the HTML, which may appear multiple times in the page:

```
<b><font color="#CC0000">
<span class="PageText_L331n">(Out of Stock)</span>
</font></b>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Let me just suggest you **don't** use `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('', '');`. I think the best way to handle this is to loop through all (children) elements and see if any text nodes contain this text. If so, remove them

Comment: Why don't you put it in a div with some class that doesn't have any styles, then `.empty()` that div.  --EDIT-- Then I noticed this was a vanilla JS question.  You can change it to `document.querySelectorAll().innerHTML = ""` or something.  Not sure about the normal JS syntax off the top of my head.

Comment: I don't think I can put the HTML into a div without some workaround. My eccommerce platform does not allow me to edit the template on the product/category pages. It only allows me to append codes to the page. Here is an example of a page with the Out of Stock text I want to hide: http://www.l-trondirect.com/Itronix-Office-and-Vehicle-Dock-Mini-Office-Dock-p/1166-001015-01r.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Like this example?

```
<div>
<span class="PageText_L328n"><strong class="prod_qty_label">
      Quantity in Stock 1
    </strong></span>

</div>
<div>
<span class="PageText_L329n"><strong class="prod_qty_label">
      Quantity in Stock 2
    </strong></span>

</div>
<div>
<span class="PageText_L330n"><strong class="prod_qty_label">
      Quantity in Stock 3
    </strong></span>

</div>
<button id="button">Remove</button>

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var PageText_L329n = document.getElementsByClassName("PageText_L329n");

function remove() {
    if (PageText_L329n[0]) {
        PageText_L329n[0].parentNode.removeChild(PageText_L329n[0]);
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", remove, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/3MmpJ/)

Also, maybe it is enough just to hide it rather than remove it from the DOM.

And for clearing text

```
<b><font color="#CC0000">
<span class="PageText_L331n">(Out of Stock)</span>
</font></b>

<button id="clear">Clear</button>

var button = document.getElementById("clear");

function clearText() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("PageText_L331n")[0].textContent = "";
}

button.addEventListener("click", clearText, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/NxnUF/)

Comment: Hiding would be fine, too. A specific example can be found here: http://www.l-trondirect.com/Itronix-Office-and-Vehicle-Dock-Mini-Office-Dock-p/1166-001015-01r.htm
I only want to hide the line when it is "Out of Stock". I want to keep it there when there is a quantity in stock.

As for the second part, that code works! But only for the first instance. Is there a way I can count how many times the class repeats, so I can create a loop? Here is an example of a page with it: http://www.l-trondirect.com/General-Dynamics-s/84.htm

Comment: That is not what you stated in your original question, "I need a script to remove a line of text "Quantity in Stock:(Out of Stock)" from my product pages. The specific HTML code I'm trying to remove is:". So then you will need to search for the text and when you find it, either remove or hide the html, like demonstrated. For nodelist of elements, document.querySelectorAll(".classname"), then you can loop the nodelist.

Comment: The first part does not need to be looped. It will only appear once. It is one line of text in the webpage, but multiple lines in the source file, as quoted. Maybe I am just not understanding the code. Like I said, I have limited knowledge of Javascript. I will take some time to dissect your demonstration to make it work. I will also  play around with document.querySelectorAll(".classname") to make it work for the second part, too. Thanks!

Comment: I got the second part to work by doing this:
for(var i=0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".PageText_L331n").length; i++) {
   document.getElementsByClassName("PageText_L331n")[i].textContent = "";
 }

Comment: Now I will work on the first part. I'm sure this would take 5 minutes for an experienced coder, but I am having fun figuring out what functions to use. I'm not sure who thumbed down it, but it's the most helpful answer here. Something I can use, so I'm giving you a thumbs up. Edit: nevermind, I don't have enough rep to give you a thumbs up.